# Error: 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, compiler-errors

I'm pretty new to coding Swift, so please excuse me if this error is a simple answer!

I keep getting an error message that says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context."

```
    var findTimelineData: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sweets")
    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            for object:PFObject in objects! { // ----This is the error line---
                self.timelineData.addObject(object)
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can help the compiler know what `objects` is like this:

```
for object in objects as! [PFObject] {
    self.timelineData.addObject(object)
}
```

Comment: My example uses force-unwrapping, don't forget that this will crash if any object in the array is not a PFObject. If you think this might be your case, or in any doubt, better use optional binding like in Tom Howard's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if let pfObjects = objects as? [PFObject]
{
    for pfObject in pfObjects
    {
        self.timelineData.addObject(pfObject)
    }
}
```

...exclamation points in Swift code give me the heeby jeebies.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing some code likes:

```
for (i, view) in views { 
}
```

You need to add `enumerated`:

```
for (i, view) in views.enumerated() {
}
```

And now it should work.