# SWIFT Object in object ERROR ios

Tags: ios, swift, object, geolocation

i can not seem to figure out what is wrong.

First in my code i did not use for object in object and than i got the error:

> AnyObject is not a subtype of PFObject.

After adding for object in object i thought that it would work. But rather i get an error saying

> Value of optionale type [PFObject]? not unwrapped; did you mean: ! or
>   '?'

When i try to add a questionMark after [PFObject] the same as the first error appears.

The error appears at these two lines

```
 for object in objects as [PFObject] {
                        if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject!] {
```

Thank you for your time.

Here is all of my codes.

```
for object in objects as [PFObject] {
                    if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject!] {


                        //                        println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")

                        for near in proximityArray {
                            //                            println("here they are \(near)")

                            let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint

                            var theirLat = position?.latitude       //this is an optional
                            var theirLong = position?.longitude     //this is an optional
                            var theirLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: theirLat!, longitude: theirLong!)

                            nearArray.append(theirLocation)

                            if nearArray.isEmpty {
                                println("*** ERROR! anyone close by ***")
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                for person in nearArray {

                                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.50, 2.50)
                                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(theirLocation, span)
                                    self.MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                                    let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                                    theirAnotation.setCoordinate(theirLocation)
                                    theirAnotation.title = near["who"] as String

                                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(theirAnotation)

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        }

                        print("****** in a radius of \(radius) there are \(nearArray.count) bikers ******")

                    }
                })
        }

        filterByProximity()



    }
```

**EDIT**

**Here is ALL of my codes**

```
  //
//  ViewController.swift
//  Rulleruss
//
//  Created by Carl Thorbjørnsen on 08/01/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Fomo. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse
import CoreLocation
import MapKit







class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {





    @IBOutlet var MapView: MKMapView?





       let locationManager = CLLocationManager()




    var CurrUserGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint!


    @IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var PasswordTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var EmailTF: UITextField!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocation: [CLLocation] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)




    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        var latitude = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude

        let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude:longitude)
        let myParseId = PFUser.CurrentUser().objectId //PFUser.currentUser().objectId

        print("****** this is my geoPoint: \(myGeoPoint)")

        func sendPosition(userOfPosition: user) {

            let takePosition = PFObject(className: "Position")

            takePosition.setObject(myParseId, forKey: "who") //who
            takePosition.setObject(myGeoPoint, forKey: "where")
            takePosition.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

        }


        sendPosition(user())

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        MapView!.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        anotation.coordinate = location
        anotation.title = "my title"
        anotation.subtitle = " my subtitle"

        MapView!.addAnnotation(anotation)

        print("****** Welcome in MapViewController")

        //MARK: (471) Crossing Positions
        //*******************************************************


                var radius = 100.0

        print("****** this is my geoPoint from map view controller: \(myGeoPoint)")


        //MARK: *** let's look for other users ***

        var nearArray : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

        func filterByProximity() {
            PFQuery(className: "Position")
                .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: radius)     //(474)
                .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                    objects, error in








                    if let proximityArray = objects as! [PFObject] {


                        //                        println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")

                        for near in proximityArray {
                            //                            println("here they are \(near)")

                            let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint

                            var theirLat = position?.latitude       //this is an optional
                            var theirLong = position?.longitude     //this is an optional
                            var theirLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: theirLat!, longitude: theirLong!)

                            nearArray.append(theirLocation)

                            if nearArray.isEmpty {
                                println("*** ERROR! anyone close by ***")
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                for person in nearArray {

                                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.50, 2.50)
                                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(theirLocation, span)
                                    self.MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                                    let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                                    theirAnotation.setCoordinate(theirLocation)
                                    theirAnotation.title = near["who"] as String

                                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(theirAnotation)

                                }

                            }




                    }
                        print("****** in a radius of \(radius) there are \(nearArray.count) bikers ******")

                    }
                })
            }

         filterByProximity()



    }

















    @IBAction func LoginBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {


    Login()

    }




    @IBAction func Loggut(sender: AnyObject) {




        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

        PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock({(error) -> Void in self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginView", sender: self)

        })
    }








    func Login() {
        var user = PFUser()
        user.username = UsernameTextField.text
        user.password = PasswordTF.text

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(UsernameTextField.text!, password: PasswordTF.text!, block: {
            (User : PFUser?, Error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if Error == nil{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
             var Storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
             var MainVC : UIViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC") as! UIViewController

                self.presentViewController(MainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)




            }

            }
            else{


            // Examine the error object and inform the user.
            let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Russeradar", message: "Passordet eller brukernavnet er feil." , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertcontroller,animated: true, completion: nil)




        }



        })

    }

    @IBAction func SignUpBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        SignUp()

    }



    func SignUp(){
        var user = PFUser()
        user.username = UsernameTextField.text
        user.password = PasswordTF.text
        user.email = EmailTF.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Russeradar", message: "Din bruker er nå opprettet! Du kan nå logge in" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alertcontroller,animated: true, completion: nil)


            } else {
                // Examine the error object and inform the user.
                let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Russeradar", message: "Din bruker kunne ikke opprettes. Prøv på nytt senere!" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alertcontroller,animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        if (MapView?.userLocation.location == nil){
        NSLog("No location");

           }
        self.MapView?.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
        self.MapView?.showsUserLocation = true


        locationManager.delegate = self


        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()





        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()






    }










    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.MapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()



    }







    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)

    }
    func MapView(MapView: MKMapView, didFailToLocateUserWithError error: NSError) {
     print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)

    }

















}
```

Comment: What's the type of `objects`?

Comment: The PFObjects. Such as location ect.

Comment: I mean the actual type of the variable `objects`as defined in code or inferred by the compiler. You can see it by ⌥-click the variable name in Xcode.

Comment: To be honest. i could not find it. Is it another way i can explain?

Comment: Try to find the definition of it. Can either be `let ...`, `var ...` or a parameter of a method.

Comment: Thank you for your pationt Mr. Hendriks. @GuidoHendriks. I did update the code now and marked it with **EDIT** i belive that is the varibles for object

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's still not where the variable is declared. You can see the declaration by either ⌥- or ⌘-clicking the variable name anywhere it's used.

Comment: Okei, i am sorry. I updated it now with all of the codes. I appriciate you time and help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211809/error-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to force unwrap it using an "!" instead of a "?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on in your code, I think it's a bit strange what you're doing. Since `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` calls the closure with an parameter that's an `[AnyObject]?`, you'll need to cast that to `[PFObject]`. The code below handles that casting properly and could replace some of the code you used.

```
PFQuery(className: "Position").findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ objects, error in
    if let positions = objects as? [PFObject] {
        for position in positions {
            // Do whatever you want with the PFObject here...
        }
    }
})
```

This part of your code is that needs replacement:

```
for object in objects as [PFObject] {
    if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject!] {
        for near in proximityArray {
```