# Array creation causes 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I am very new to Swift. Please forgive if my question sounds stupid.

I have declared a structure as follows:

```
struct RecorderState 
{
    var setupComplete: Bool
    var dataFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription
    var queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef>
    var buffers: [AudioQueueBufferRef]
    var recordFile: AudioFileID
    var bufferByteSize: UInt32
    var currentPacket: Int64
    var isRunning: Bool
    var recordPacket: Int64
    var errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?
}
```

Now I need to write the init method of my class which initializes a structure inside it.

```
class SimplePCMRecorder : NSObject
{
    private var recorderState: RecorderState

    init(numberBuffers: Int)
    {
        self.recorderState = RecorderState(
            setupComplete: false,
            dataFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription(),
            queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef>.alloc(1),
            buffers: Array<AudioQueueBufferRef>(repeating: 0, count: numberBuffers),
            recordFile:AudioFileID(),
            bufferByteSize: 0,
            currentPacket: 0,
            isRunning: false,
            recordPacket: 0,
            errorHandler: nil
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is, the error,  'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' keeps on showing on the line `buffers: Array<AudioQueueBufferRef>(repeating: 0, count: numberBuffers)`.

[image]

I tried the other way but still the same.

[image]

From what I read from here [Error: 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211809/error-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context) is that the compiler does not know the type of object therefore it shows the error. But here, I already declared it.

I tried to cast it again by adding as after the constructor method but still didn't work.

[image]

I don't understand why. I have declared the type of variable of buffers to be an `Array` containing `AudioQueueBufferRef`. But how come the compiler still can't detect that?

Comment: `AudioQueueBufferRef` is a typealias for  `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueBuffer>`, i.e. you have to pass a pointer to `AudioQueueBuffer` as the initial value, you cannot pass `0`.

Comment: @MartinR Hi, thank you! Now that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of [Martin R's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690452/array-creation-causes-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context#comment82340135_47690452)
comment above.

```
class SimplePCMRecorder : NSObject
{
    private var recorderState: RecorderState
    init(numberBuffers: Int)
    {

        self.recorderState = RecorderState(
            setupComplete: false,
            dataFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription(),
            queue: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueRef>.allocate(capacity: 1),
            buffers: Array<UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueBuffer>>(repeating: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioQueueBuffer>(bitPattern: 0)! , count: numberBuffers),
            recordFile:AudioFileID(bitPattern: 0)!,
            bufferByteSize: 0,
            currentPacket: 0,
            isRunning: false,
            recordPacket: 0,
            errorHandler: nil
        )
    }
}
```